# How to enable other checkboxes in recycler view if previous checkbox is checked (other checkboxes are disabled at first)?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-checkbox, oncheckedchanged

What I want to do is if **April** and **May** have a due amount then a user cannot *select* **May** if **April** is *not selected*. First, a user has to select **April** then the **May** checkbox will get *enabled*. If **May** is selected then **June** will get *enabled*.

I am not able to get position of the checkboxes so that I can do the same.

[image]

```
@Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull FeeHolder holder, int position) {
      holder.textView_fee.setText(Integer.toString(list.get(position).getFeeAmount()));
      holder.textView_due.setText(Integer.toString(list.get(position).getDueAmount()));
      holder.checkBox.setText(list.get(position).getInstallmentName());

      holder.checkBox.setTag(Integer.toString(position));
      arrayList.add(holder.checkBox);
      /*if (holder.checkBox.isChecked()) {
          arrayList.add(holder.checkBox);
      }*/
      holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
          @Override
          public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

          }
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `selected` property *(with getters and setters)* to your `list` array and here's a code fragment to play with.

```java
if (position > 0) {
  YourObject obj = list.get(position - 1);
  if(obj.dueAmount() > 0) {
    if(obj.isSelected()) {
      holder.checkBox.setEnabled(true)
    } else {
      holder.checkBox.setEnabled(false)
    }
  } else {
    holder.checkBox.setEnabled(true)
  }
}
```

Then, on your `setOnCheckedChangeListener`, update your object's `selected` property accordingly.

PS: This applies a chain effect if previous items have `dueAmount > 0`

Comment: What's YourObject in this case?

Comment: @Osama `YourObject` is an instance of your `Object` from your `list` array

Comment: @Osama `.isSelected()` from `YourObject` should return the current value for your `selected` property.

Comment: `.isSelected()` is working with checkbox instance not with `YourObject` instance. `if (obj.isSelected())` is showing error.

Comment: I see, but using your checkbox instance doesn't actually check if the previous checkbox is selected. It only checks if your current checkbox is selected, not the previous one.